# Illegal iphone api function usage

Tags: iphone

Can I use `objc_getClassList` and `class_getSuperclass` in my iPhone application?
Why "objc/objc-runtime.h" is not present when compiling for the device?
PS: Actually I am using 4.2 SDK

Comment: Yes, it is possible to get the objc reflection methods to work on a device.  There is some minor trick required to do so.  Unfortunately I can't remember what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For objc_getClassList not working on the device, I believe the problem is that the class definitions are in a static library, so you must add the -ObjC flag to the linker. The result of doing this is that the "entire" static library that defines a particular class will be loaded. See this link from [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html)

According to [Apple's runtime reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), you should use "superclass" instead of class_getSuperclass

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works also on the device, but my concerne is: will my application be rejected by apple when including these calls or not? Is there any reference list somewhere to check for this?

Comment: I don't see why they would reject it. You are using APIs that Apple themselves specify and have documentation for.